# ExtJs 6 : Data added to store at application launch not persisted

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm creating a test application in EXT 6 Beta and I'm having a problem populating my stores. I'm trying to populate the stores with test data in the launch function in the Ext.application. The main bits of code are below, with various console.logs present.

```
Ext.define('myApp.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    name: 'myApp',
    // stores: ['Items'],
    requires: [ 'myApp.store.Items' ],
    launch: function () {
        var createTestData = function(){ ... }
        var testData = createTestData();
        this.getStore('Items').add(testData);
        console.log(2,this.getStore('Items').getData());
    }
});
```

The store:

```
Ext.define('myApp.store.Items', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.items',
    model: 'myApp.Item',
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

The grid:

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.main.ItemList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    requires: [ 'myApp.store.Items' ],
    title: 'Items',
    store: { type: 'items' },
    columns: [ ... ],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(){
            console.log(1, this.getStore().getData());
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(
                function(){
                    console.log(3, self.getStore().getData());
                }, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

The console logs output in this order: 1, 2, 3. Number 1 has data, but neither 2 nor 3 do.

I tried setting the store to a singleton, but this just throws an error saying a Singleton cannot be instantiated. How can I get data to stay in the store or repeatedly access the same store?

Comment: The code you've got above doesn't really make sense. The grid will create a new store instance of type 'items'. The stuff in the launch method doesn't  refer to the same store that the grid had, rather a singleton instance shared across the app.

Comment: I think you need to post more code. For example, you don't show where the view is created. Something runnable would be ideal.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I was assuming the the application or the grid created an instance of the store, which would then be reused. How can I refer to the same store?

Comment: I cannot really post runnable code as there is quite a lot and some of it I cannot post due to limitations at work.

Comment: Assuming you want to share that store instance, it is created with an id 'Items', so in your grid definition you should be able to put `store: 'Items'`

Comment: That was it. I missed that, should have seen that was where it was recreating the store. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the comments the problem was the grid creating a new store rather than using the same one as the Ext.application. So to fix this issue:

The app:

```
Ext.define('myApp.Application', {
    ...
    stores: ['Items'],
    // requires: [ 'myApp.store.Items' ],
    ...
});
```

The grid:

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.main.ItemList', {
    ...
    requires: [
        'myApp.store.Items'
    ],
    store: 'Items', // Refers to the store ID
    // store: { type: 'items' }, (Created a new store)
    ...
});
```

The store:

```
Ext.define('myApp.store.Items', {
    ...
    id: 'Items',
    ...
});
```